# Why does INCBIN`d var throw an error when accessed?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266

- VSCode, PlatformIO
- ESP8266 nodeMCU v3.0
- PIO`s INCBIN lib https://github.com/AlexIII/incbin-arduino?utm_source=platformio&utm_medium=piohome

I load by INCBIN lib one file to ESP8266.
I try to print first datum.

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "incbin.h"

INCBIN(my, "path/to/file.someExtension");

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(*gmyData)
}

void loop(){}
```

monitor out

```
Exception (3):
epc1=0x40201098 epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x40238b14 depc=0x00000000

LoadStoreError: Processor internal physical address or data error during load or store
  epc1=0x40201098 in setup at ??:?
  excvaddr=0x40238b14 in ethernet_input at ??:?

>>>stack>>>

ctx: cont
sp: 3ffffe00 end: 3fffffc0 offset: 0190
3fffff90:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffee534 40201093  
3fffffa0:  feefeffe feefeffe 3ffee66c 40201e00  
3fffffb0:  feefeffe feefeffe 3ffe85d8 40100cc1  
<<<stack<<<

0x40201093 in setup at ??:?
0x40201e00 in loop_wrapper() at core_esp8266_main.cpp:?
0x40100cc1 in cont_wrapper at ??:?
```

This also throws error.

```
  uint8_t datum = *gmyData;
  Serial.println(datum);
```

## edit

Tests show that `Serial.println()`  is not guilty. It's all about incbin'd var access.

test, which throws aforementioned exception:

```
  int i;
  if (*gmyData > 0)
    i = 1;
  else
    i = 2;
  Serial.println(i);
```

File is a "primary" certificate `gtsltsr.crt` from  point 1.b from https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge#using_a_long-term_mqtt_domain

I tried to read first byte in main code sample just to check correctness.

Comment: What does "this doesn't work too" mean? Similar error, or just not the output you expect? If it's not the output you expect then what is it? What's in the file you're trying to include?

Comment: @romkey , I have edited post with necessary info